# Jenkins in docker centos container

Tags: docker

Is it possible to install Jenkins in docker Linux containers and use it. Please specify the step by step process

I created centos container and installed Jenkins it. but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should expose port 8080 to the host-machine and then you can browse jenkin by pointing your browser to

Exposing a port should have be done while creating a container and map accordingly.
like-

```
$ docker run -p 48080:8080 --name container-name your-centos-image-name:tag
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [official jenkins image](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins):

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins
```

Comment: Instead of using Jenkins official image can't we create our own image. I mean running a fresh centos image and install Jenkins and all dependencies in it, and using it.